# How to plot a line density plot using data file

Tags: plotting

I am using the following code to generate a density plot using a data file (which has three columns). The first column is X axis and second column is Y axis and the third column is the color. It gives me a plot with different color points.

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Style[{AvsCvsThetaData[[i, {1, 2}]]}, 
   Hue[AvsCvsThetaData[[i, 3]]/(Pi)]], {i, Length[AvsCvsThetaData]}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {"A", "C"}, 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 RotateLabel -> False, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Now suppose, instead of the points, I want a line connecting all the points and the color of the line should change according to the 3rd column. I don't really know whether it is possible to do or not. Can anyone suggest something!

Comment: Can you add a little of the data so we know what you're working with? You probably want to check out `ListLinePlot` and `ColorFunction`.

Comment: do you want to color the line based on (the third coordinate of) the first point or do you prefer to blend the colors of the two end points of the a line?

Comment: @CarlLange: ListLinePlot does not work here. My data file has the numerical values of a function $f(x,y,z)$. I don't know the functional form of the function otherwise I could have used ParametricPlot.

Comment: @kglr: As I have different color for different point (based on the value of 3rd coordinate at that point), I want to connect those two point  using a linear interpolation and then color can go accordingly.

Comment: Please do not use tags unrelated to the problem that are you asking about (is this problem specific to Mathematica Online?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[123]
data = Join[RandomReal[10, {100, 2}], List /@ RandomReal[{0, Pi}, 100], 2];

ListPlot[Table[Style[{data[[i, {1, 2}]]}, Hue[data[[i, 3]]/(Pi)]], {i, 
   Length[data]}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
 Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 FrameLabel -> {"A", "C"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 RotateLabel -> False, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

One possible way is to use `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{Hue[#[[3]]/Pi], PointSize[Large], Point[#[[;; 2]]]} & /@ data, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"A", "C"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 RotateLabel -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

To color each line base on the color of its first point:

```
Graphics[{Hue[#[[1, 3]]/Pi], Thick, Line[#[[All, ;; 2]]]} & /@ Partition[data, 2, 1], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"A", "C"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 RotateLabel -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

To color each line by blending the colors of its endpoints:

```
Graphics[{Thick, Line[data[[All, ;; 2]], VertexColors -> (Hue /@ (data[[All, 3]]/Pi))]},
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"A", "C"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 RotateLabel -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks dude. I must admit you are excellent in using mathematica.